# How can I do computations on the fly within the vagrant file

Tags: ruby, shell, vagrant, vagrantfile

How can I compute the hash on the fly within the vagrant file based on some input, for e.g. I do

```
# shell
$ echo "machine13" | sha256sum | cut -c1-12 
2372240456c2

# vagrantfile
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.hostname = "machine13"
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "eth0", use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true,  :mac => "2372240456c2"
end
```

Comment: is `machine13` in  `echo "machine13" | sha256sum | cut -c1-12` dynamic or something that you can hardcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to run a bash command and get its output to a variable in your Vagrantfile, you could use the ruby's back ticks to execute the command.

For example, your Vagrantfile:

```
# Vagrantfile
my_hostname = "machine12"
mac_hash = `echo #{my_hostname} | sha256sum | cut -c1-12`

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.hostname = my_hostname
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "eth0", use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true,  :mac => mac_hash
end
```

Comment: how can I set machine13 to a variable and define it only once?

Comment: Edited the answer to show that. You would use Ruby's variable substitution like you would use for strings.

Comment: Or are you asking if you could pass this `machine13` dynamically when you run `vagrant up` in the console and access it in the Vagrantfile ?